# How to select between 2 data in SQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
Table 1
-------
ID
score

Table 2
-------
ID
score_from
score_to
```

How do I get ID from Table 2, if I have score='12' in Table1 based on score_from and score_to in Table 2 ?

```
Contents of Table1:
----------------------
ID          |Score   |
----------------------
1           |12      |
----------------------
2           |40      |
----------------------

Contents of Table2:
------------------------------
ID       |score_from|score_to|
------------------------------
1        |0         |20      |
------------------------------
2        |21        |40      |
------------------------------
```

If I have score='12' from table1, how can I write a query to get ID='1' in table2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
SELECT a.`ID`, a.`Score`, b.`ID`, b.`score_from`, b.`score_to`
FROM   table1 a, table2 b
WHERE  (a.score BETWEEN b.score_from AND b.score_to) AND
        (a.score = 12)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e53c9/7)

or if you want only the `ID`

```
SELECT b.`ID`
FROM   table1 a, table2 b
WHERE  (a.score BETWEEN b.score_from AND b.score_to) AND
        (a.score = 12)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e53c9/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id from table t1 ,table t2
where t1.score between t2.score_from and t2.score_to;
```